# Is there a difference between a Marksman and Sniper?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

The Assault (Marksman) and Stealth (Sniper) classes both use long range rifles that look the same. Are there any differences that make one weapon better than the other or are fire-rate, damage, zoom, accuracy and recoil all the same? Aside from the class's starting health and class ability is there anything that makes one long range rifle better then the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't play sniper that often, but i didn't notice a significant difference between the rifles. However, there is a huge difference due to the class ability which changes the roles completely.

Assault Snipers can see cloaked units through their scopes, which makes them ideal countersnipers against stealth snipers on the more open maps while stealth snipers are more useful against anything else that can't see them.

When in doubt, go with stealth sniper.

Comment: plus the health difference, I prefer assualt because i dont get one shotted by everything